# Create categorical variable from mutually exclusive dummy variables

Tags: r, dataframe, categorical-data, dummy-variable

How can I create a categorical variable from mutually exclusive dummy variables (taking values 0/1)?

Basically I am looking for the exact opposite of this solution: (https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781787124479/1/01lvl1sec22/creating-dummies-for-categorical-variables).

Would appreciate a base R solution.

For example, I have the following data:

```
dummy.df <- structure(c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                        0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
            .Dim = c(10L, 4L), 
            .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("State.NJ", "State.NY", "State.TX", "State.VA")))
```

```
          State.NJ State.NY State.TX State.VA
     [1,]        1        0        0        0
     [2,]        0        1        0        0
     [3,]        1        0        0        0
     [4,]        0        0        0        1
     [5,]        0        1        0        0
     [6,]        0        0        1        0
     [7,]        1        0        0        0
     [8,]        0        0        0        1
     [9,]        0        0        1        0
    [10,]        0        0        0        1
```

I would like to get the following results

```
   state
1     NJ
2     NY
3     NJ
4     VA
5     NY
6     TX
7     NJ
8     VA
9     TX
10    VA

cat.var <- structure(list(state = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("NJ", "NY", "TX", "VA"), class = "factor")), 
                    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Reconstruct a categorical variable from dummies in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130366/reconstruct-a-categorical-variable-from-dummies-in-r)

Answer (score 5):

```
# toy data
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,0,0,0,0), b = c(0,1,0,1,0), c = c(0,0,1,0,1))

df$cat <- apply(df, 1, function(i) names(df)[which(i == 1)])
```

Result:

```
> df
  a b c cat
1 1 0 0   a
2 0 1 0   b
3 0 0 1   c
4 0 1 0   b
5 0 0 1   c
```

To generalize, you'll need to play with the `df` and `names(df)` part, but you get the drift. One option would be to make a function, e.g.,

```
catmaker <- function(data, varnames, catname) {

  data[,catname] <- apply(data[,varnames], 1, function(i) varnames[which(i == 1)])

  return(data)

}

newdf <- catmaker(data = df, varnames = c("a", "b", "c"), catname = "newcat")
```

One nice aspect of the functional approach is that it is robust to variations in the order of names in the vector of column names you feed into it. I.e., `varnames = c("c", "a", "b")` produces the same result as `varnames = c("a", "b", "c")`.

P.S. You added some example data after I posted this. The function works on your example, as long as you convert `dummy.df` to a data frame first, e.g., `catmaker(data = as.data.frame(dummy.df), varnames = colnames(dummy.df), "State")` does the job.

Answer (score 2):

*You can use `tidyr::gather`:*

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

as_tibble(dummy.df) %>%  
  mutate(id =1:n()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(., -id, values_to = "Value", 
                  names_to = c("txt","State"), names_sep = "\\.") %>% 
  filter(Value ==1) %>%  select(State)
```

```
#> # A tibble: 10 x 1
#>    State
#>    <chr>
#>  1 NJ   
#>  2 NY   
#>  3 NJ   
#>  4 VA   
#>  5 NY   
#>  6 TX   
#>  7 NJ   
#>  8 VA   
#>  9 TX   
#> 10 VA
```

Comment: this is actually the exact opposite from what I am asking

Comment: Yeah, I am used to see the input first and then the output. I will edit shortly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
states <- names(dummy.df)[max.col(dummy.df)]
```

Or if as in your example it's a matrix you'd need to use `colnames()`:

```
colnames(dummy.df)[max.col(dummy.df)]
```

Then just clean it up with `sub()`:

```
sub(".*\\.", "", states)

"NJ" "NY" "NJ" "VA" "NY" "TX" "NJ" "VA" "TX" "VA"
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT : with your data**

One way with `model.matrix` for dummy creation and matrix multiplication :

```r
dummy.df<-structure(c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                      0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(10L, 4L
                      ), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("State.NJ", "State.NY", "State.TX", 
                                                  "State.VA")))
level_names <- colnames(dummy.df)

# use matrix multiplication to extract wanted level
res <- dummy.df%*%1:ncol(dummy.df)

# clean up
res <- as.numeric(res)
factor(res, labels = level_names)
#>  [1] State.NJ State.NY State.NJ State.VA State.NY State.TX State.NJ
#>  [8] State.VA State.TX State.VA
#> Levels: State.NJ State.NY State.TX State.VA
```

General reprex :

```r
# create factor and dummy target y
dfr <- data.frame(vec = gl(n = 3, k = 3, labels = letters[1:3]),
                  y = 1:9)
dfr
#>   vec y
#> 1   a 1
#> 2   a 2
#> 3   a 3
#> 4   b 4
#> 5   b 5
#> 6   b 6
#> 7   c 7
#> 8   c 8
#> 9   c 9
```

```r
# dummies creation
dfr_dummy <- model.matrix(y ~ 0 + vec, data = dfr)

# use matrix multiplication to extract wanted level
res <- dfr_dummy%*%c(1,2,3)

# clean up
res <- as.numeric(res)
factor(res, labels = letters[1:3])
#> [1] a a a b b b c c c
#> Levels: a b c
```